# show all results on one page (gem kaminari)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, navigation, kaminari

I have data and they be cut on some pages (10 results per page).

code in controller:

```
@messages = Message.order('id DESC').page params[:page]
```

How I can show all results on one page if I want? It similar as `'see all'` on page navigate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put a very high limit in the per_page option if you still want the paginate helpers to work in your view.

```
@messages = Message.order('id DESC').page params[:page]
if params[:all]
  @messages = @messages.per_page(Message.count) # you can also hardcod' it
end
```

Comment: Just fyi, for more recent versions, instead of `.per_page` it is `.per`